# html decode('utf-8') csv double lines (python 3)

Tags: python, html, json, python-3.x, csv

I am reading a CSV dump via an API, the download is a string (see example below) but when I decode it into a CSV file I get an extra blank line between the data line.

What do I need to do to remove these extra lines?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json, ast
import datetime
import time
import LOM_Config
import LOM_GetTokenID

def CVS_Download(LOMID, LOMDeviceName):

    global dtime
    dtime = time.time()

token_string = LOM_GetTokenID.GetTokenID()
    tempstring = 'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/' + str(LOMID) + '/csv/?token=' +  str(token_string) + '&timestamp_to=' + str(dtime)  + '&length_of_time=31557600' 
    file = urlopen(tempstring)
    html = file.read()
    print(html)
    html = html.decode('utf-8')
    tmpstring = LOMDeviceName + '.csv'
    f = open(tmpstring,'a')
    f.write(str(html))
    f.close
```

This is the HTML dump

```
b'time,Light Level,Air Pressure,Humidity,Temperature,CO2,Pollution,Sound\r\n2017-04-01 06:55:00+00:00,56.0,1004.52001953125,56.7000007629395,20.7999992370605,0.0,0.0,38.2862205505371\r\n2017-04-01 06:56:00+00:00,142.0,1004.53002929688,56.5999984741211,20.7999992370605,0.0,0.0,37.7092018127441\r\n
```

The CSV file becomes

```
time,Light Level,Air Pressure,Humidity,Temperature,CO2,Pollution,Sound

2017-04-01 06:55:00+00:00,56.0,1004.52001953125,56.7000007629395,20.7999992370605,0.0,0.0,38.2862205505371

2017-04-01 06:56:00+00:00,142.0,1004.53002929688,56.5999984741211,20.7999992370605,0.0,0.0,37.7092018127441

2017-04-01 06:57:00+00:00,142.0,1004.57000732422,56.5,20.7000007629395,0.0,34.6334953308105,39.8081016540527

2017-04-01 06:58:00+00:00,132.0,1004.50994873047,56.5,20.7000007629395,0.0,25.9586906433105,33.675178527832

2017-04-01 06:59:00+00:00,132.0,1004.55004882812,56.5,20.7000007629395,0.0,21.750114440918,32.988037109375
```

Answer (score 1):

A bytestring can handle your text independently from your operating system behaviour. Try to write the file also in this filemode by using e.g.:

```
teststring = b'time,Light Level,Air Pressure,Humidity,Temperature,CO2,Pollution,Sound\r\n2017-04-01 06:55:00+00:00,56.0,1004.52001953125,56.7000007629395,20.7999992370605,0.0,0.0,38.2862205505371\r\n2017-04-01 06:56:00+00:00,142.0,1004.53002929688,56.5999984741211,20.7999992370605,0.0,0.0,37.7092018127441\r\n'

f = open("testfile.csv", 'ab')  # <- 'b' = bytestring
f.write(teststring)  # <- without converting it to str
f.close()
```